# Did the Stack Overflow css just change?

Tags: discussion, design

I might be going crazy, but the Stack Overflow page looks... different. The question titles are thinner, the background for questions with one of your favorite tags is less orange, and a few other things seem off.

Did Stack Overflow just go through a style update?

(ps, if it did, let me be the first to say I don't like it).

Comment: Yes, it did just change.

Comment: Nope, going crazy.

Comment: You can't tell if it changed or not, but you know you don't like it?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I was 99% sure it changed, but I just didnt see any announcements. By the way, whats with all the downvotes?

Comment: It was long in the making and announced.

Comment: _slow clap_ @BilltheLizard _slow clap_

Comment: Noooo. I thought you were kidding about that design change (damage). It's all somehow inflated, [review buttons are so blue](http://i.imgur.com/QbMZ8hn.png), [comments on deleted posts are badly readable](http://i.imgur.com/LOowFMr.png)... Grrrr!

Comment: I like it. I can fit more code on one line now without having to side-scroll

Comment: @Deduplicator announced where? Some of us don't hang out on Meta every day. I checked the blog and there's nuthin.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Stack Overflow Design Update (the dupe) was [meta-tag:featured] for quite some time. Which means it was always shown on the main-site too.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm on the site nearly every day and I never saw it.

Answer (score 6):

It appears so, and it looks too muted and "whispy" to me.